# How to redirect from Github to another site except for the index without using .htaccess

Tags: html, github, redirect, github-pages

I have a github pages site without jekyll, but with a custom domain (*example.com*).

Is there a way to redirect all from that site to another site except for the main page (index.html)? E.g. *example.com/fun* redirects to *anotherexample.com/fun* but *example.com* doesn’t redirect anywhere.

Please note that GitHub pages doesn’t support .htaccess

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript way to do this would be to add the following snippet to the `<head>` section of the pages you want to redirect:

```
<script>
  window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");
</script>
```

The above script will redirect the pages to `https://www.example.com`.

---

A pure HTML way of doing this would be to add the following meta tag to the `<head>` section of the pages you want to redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://www.example.com'" />
```

The above meta tag will redirect the pages to `https://www.example.com` after `0` seconds but  browsers might not always respond to this meta tag in a same unified way and according to a few seo articles online, search engines may consider your site spammy if you have too many meta refresh redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JavaScript like this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var page = path.split("/").pop();

if(page !== 'index.html' || path !== '/'){
  window.location.replace("http://example.com");
}
```

hope this helps